# Problems with remote access, won't display password

Tags: ssh, remote-access, remote

I am remote accessing a computer on windows using ssh.  The computers connect, but when I try to type in my password no characters pop up and when I do type my correct password in nothing happens.  This is the first time remote accessing this computer, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

#### Make sure you are using ssh correctly.

For example, you must supply the username on the remote system if it's different than your local username.

`ssh remoteUserName@remote.computer.com`

When the connection is established, you should be prompted to enter a password. There will not be any feedback for what is being typed. If your login is successful you will usually get a brief message and a command prompt, if not you will be asked to enter the password again. Some servers are set up to only allow a few failed attempts, and could possibly set a delay for when you can try again. Worse case, if the sysadmin has some strict security set up, too many failed attempts will lock you out until an admin unlocks your account.